# Validating Google Cloud Platform service usage quota

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, quota

I have a project on Google Cloud Platform and I have created a Service Account with some roles. I want to validate the quota for the project I'm using, with Go API. I would like to get an example of using the appropriate Go client library for this purpose.

Comment: Do you want to request the serviceusage API with Go? Like [this API](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/services.consumerQuotaMetrics.limits.consumerOverrides/list)

Answer (score 0):

After investigating in the [**Official Google APis Go Client Library**](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/master/serviceusage/v1beta1/serviceusage-gen.go), I found the code for Service Usage.

You can use the following code in order to call the Service Usage API with Go Client Library:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
"io/ioutil"

"golang.org/x/net/context"
"golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
"google.golang.org/api/serviceusage/v1beta1"
)

func main() {
// Download the Private Key from your IAM & Admin and add
// the Service Account private key path
serviceAccountFile := "credentials.json"

// Read the private key
serviceAccountJSON, err := ioutil.ReadFile(serviceAccountFile)
if err != nil {
// Handle error
}

// Add the scopes
config, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(serviceAccountJSON, serviceusage.CloudPlatformScope, serviceusage.CloudPlatformReadOnlyScope)

// Add the service account.
config.Subject = "serviceaccount@domain.com"

srv, err := serviceusage.New(config.Client(context.Background()))
if err != nil {
// Handle error
}

// REQUEST: https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/services.consumerQuotaMetrics.limits.consumerOverrides/list
resp, err := srv.Services.ConsumerQuotaMetrics.Limits.ConsumerOverrides.List("projects/<PROJECT-NUMBER>/services/compute.googleapis.com/consumerQuotaMetrics/compute.googleapis.com%2Fcpus/limits/%2Fproject%2Fregion").Do()
if err != nil {
// Handle error
}

// Handle your response
fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

Please make sure that the credentials.json is in the same directory.

This [line](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/blob/master/serviceusage/v1beta1/serviceusage-gen.go#L2695) specifies the response body. Keep in mind that this is in Beta.